# jQuery add class based on page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url

I have what I *think* is a simple question but I can't get it to work for the life of me.

All I want to do is add some javascript to the page that adds a class to the main page container based on the URL.

Let's say I have a site at root.com and the following html structure (loosely speaking):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="wrapper">
      Blah, blah, blah
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is a script that, if the page = (for example) root.com/technology, it adds a class to the main div. So the div would now look like:

```
     <div id="main" class="wrapper tech">
```

I've loaded jquery, so I'd like to do it that way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `window.location` to get the current URL, and then switch based on that:

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  if(/technology/.test(loc)) {
    $('#main').addClass('tech');
  }
});
```

This uses a regular expression to see if the URL contains a particular phrase (notably: `technology`), and if so, adds a class to the `#main` element.

Comment: @alex vidal It works fine for me but it's loading a bit later than normal. I'm using this action to maintain a sub menu open once the user is in a determined  Therefore the user can see after 1-2secs how the sub category menu opens. I would like it to do this instantly, how can I avoid this?

Comment: How can this be modified to work if you at the route (homepage) of the site?

Comment: Thanks! can you tell me what does `.test` do?

Answer (score 8):

Well, here is how I would do it:

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case '/technology':
        $('#main').addClass('tech');
        break;
    case '/something':
        // code block
        break;
    case '/somestuff':
        $('#main').addClass('some');
        break;
    default: 
        // code block
}
```

This way, you keep your code clean and you can easily add another case.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties) what `window.location.pathname` means.

Comment: I like this because, as you say, you can easily add another case without mucking things up. But I can't get it to work...

Comment: I like this answer better then the selected 'best' answer. Switch statements are way more clean then writing out conditionals.

Comment: @MattMartin that's probably because you need to add `break;` at the end of each case. That was the _case_ for me.. lol

Answer (score 3):

would something like below help? based on other answer, just by doing

> console.log(window.location)

, you can wealth wealth of information related to your location object

```
     if(window.location.href=== "root.com/technology") {
         $("#main").addClass("tech");
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) built-in object to determine full URL or some parts of it.

Comment: Clearly this is correct, but it doesn't completely answer my question of *how* to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(function(){
        var cUrl = window.location.href;
         $(".product-type-swatches__list a").each(function(){
                 if ($(this).attr("href") == cUrl){
                         $(this).addClass("is-selected");
                 }
         });
    });
```