# How to add the class to menu item based on how the URL starts?

Tags: jquery, menu, addclass

In my website directory "foto" I have a lot of articles beginig with url "http://example.com/foto/article-name" or "http://example.com/tech/article-name"

and I have a menu item with url "http://example.com/foto/".

How to highlight my menu item "FOTO" when one of articles is shown in case that these articles don't have a menu link. In other words, I would like to have a condition:

if the URL starts with "http://example.com/**foto**/" hightlight menu item **FOTO**
or if the URL starts with "http://example.com/**demo**" highlight menu item **VIDEO**,

that means that URL of the article and menu item may not start the same URL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't transmit an identifier with PHP (or whatever you're using for a backend), which tells you what page you're on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery add class based on page URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983091/jquery-add-class-based-on-page-url)

Comment: He means, that if there's no 'backend', then every page is a single page you need to create individually. Which, in turn, means, that you can input a hidden field (css-style display:none;) containing 'who am I?). And according to THIS field (which you will load with JS), you can determine which highlight you want to set.

Comment: it looks like dublicate, I will try..

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var url = window.location.href; // Get the current URL

// Check for foto inside URL //
if (url.indexOf("foto") != -1​){
    alert('foto');

    // Add selected class to menu item //
    $('#menu_item_id').addClass('selected');
}​​​​​​​
```

You can then simply add additional checks for other menu items titles.

I hope this helps!

Comment: well, I tried it works, thank you! but do you know what menu item will be highligted in case I have subdirectory "demo" that appear in the URL example.com/foto/demo/article-name and have two menu items FOTO and DEMO and two rules in my script url.indexOf('foto') and url.indexOf('demo') ?

Comment: and I deleted alert('foto'); as I don't need to view alert window. Could you explain what purpose of "!= 1"? to alert "-1" in case of "foto" was never find?

Comment: So, now I have a problem, when I started to add other menu item rules, I realised that this script doesn't remove the class "selected" from previews menu item. I added ($('#navigation li').removeClass('selected'); but it doesn' help. What is wrong? Now it looks like   if (url.indexOf("foto")) {
$('#navigation li').removeClass('selected');
    $("#lifoto").addClass('selected');
  }
else
  if (url.indexOf("demo")) {
 $('#navigation li').removeClass('selected');
    $("#lidemo").addClass('selected');
  }