# Setting the CSS class to "current" for the navigation menu in ASP Classic

Tags: css, asp-classic, menu, switch-statement

I have an include file that contains the primary navigation menu for the site. I want to be able to set a CSS class for the current page. This is what I've been able to put together so far:

```
    public function GetFileName()
        Dim files, url, segments, current

        'get then current url from the server variables
        url = Request.ServerVariables("path_info")

        segments = split(url,"/")

        'read the last segment
        url = segments(ubound(segments))
        GetFileName = url
    end function

        if  GetFileName = "index.asp" then
            current = "current"
        else
            current = ""
        end if
```

I'm thinking that a Select Case statement would be the thing to use in this scenario, I'm just not sure how to go about constructing it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly how large a menu are we talking about? Some options are fine if you're only talking about a few items, but get a little ... burdensome ... if there are a lot of items to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the definition of `Iif` to your code (from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219271 )

```
Function IIf(i,j,k)
    If i Then IIf = j Else IIf = k
End Function
```

I assume you have something like this.

```
<li><a href="somepage.asp">Click me to go somewhere</a></li>
```

You can do this:

```
<li><a href="somepage.asp" class="<%= Iif(current = "index.asp", "current", "") %>">Click me to go somewhere</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in jquery

[jQuery add class based on page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983091/jquery-add-class-based-on-page-url)

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href;
  if(/index.asp/.test(loc)) {
    $(body).addClass('index');
  }
});
```