# add/change class accordion element on the next page when click on a link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, accordion, addclass

Let me explain what i mean because its hard to explain it in the title.
On my homepage i got 3 links to my contact page,

- let us call u back
- send us and email
- make an appointment

on my contact page i got those 3 elements in a bootstrap accordion element.
when u click on 1 it opens and shows a form, its adds the class 'in' to the element.

Now i want: when i click on one of those 3 links on my homepage, it adds the class 'in' to the selected element so that accordion element is open.

Anyone knows if this is possible and how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people with the same question/problem/issue.

I used this question for my issue.

[jQuery add class based on page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983091/jquery-add-class-based-on-page-url),

just adding the 'in' class depending on the URL