# jQuery: Add class based on url parameters

Tags: jquery

I have an 'h1' tag that i need to add a class to change its colour based on the url parameter. I have two parameters that are passed so depending on which one a different class is added.

I have seen a previous post by [@Matt Martin with an answer by @Florian Margaine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9983822/2369713) which uses Switch statements which looks like a nice method, nut i cannot seem to get it to work.

I have tried the following with no success:

HTML:

`<h1 id="head" class="page-head">About Right to Manage for</h1>`

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
 switch (window.location.pathname) {
   case '?type=private':
    $('#head').addClass('private')
   case '?type=retirement':
    $('#head').addClass('retirement')
}
});
```

so I would have either of the following:

`<h1 id="head" class="page-head private">About Right to Manage for</h1>`

or

`<h1 id="head" class="page-head retirement">About Right to Manage for</h1>`

Comment: If you are not aware what `pathname` means, then log it to console or go read up on it.

Comment: (And why isn’t this done on the server side already?)

Comment: (if you really need to get the URL parameters in javascript), see `window.location.search` instead

Comment: apologies for my ignorance @Cbroe but I have researched matters. Im clearly out of my depth so any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: Well the pointer was, log it to console first of all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this (put in default the pathname) :

```
$(function() {
 switch (window.location.pathname) {
   case '/about-rtm.php?type=private':
    $('#head').addClass('private')
     break;
   case '/about-rtm.php?type=retirement':
    $('#head').addClass('retirement')
     break;
   default :
   $('h1').append(window.location.pathname);
}
});
```

It 'll append on your `h1` the **pathname**, so you can check it. (also `console.log())`

Edit

Maybe if data is not loaded, you can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

or

```
window.onload = function()
{
  //your code here
};
```

EDIT #2

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
searchParams.has('type') // true
let param = searchParams.get('type') // it could be private or retirement
if(param === 'private'){...}
else if(param === 'retirement'){....}

//or

sitch(param){

case 'private': 
.
.
.

}
```

Comment: you missed `break;` statements ;)

Comment: @SteveJoiner but the appended pathname (h1) is ''/about-rtm.php?type=private'' or "/about-rtm.php?type=retirement" ?

Comment: @Cristian I am testing this on localhost so the pathname being appended on both accounts is `/RTMF_3_root/about-rtm.php`. the parameters are not being appended.

Comment: Your efforts are appreciated @Cristian but i don't understand how I would adapt this to test.