# How to add an active class with if statement in Liquid (Shopify)

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, store

I have 2 links inside the header (one link takes you to one stores the other link takes you to another store). I need to add an active class to the store the user is on (bmx-store & skate-store are the 2 classes that need active class adding to). So if the user is on the bmx store, the link for that store becomes bold and underlined and vice versa.

```html
{% if request.url contains 'source-bmx-testing.myshopify.com' %}

{% elsif request.url contains 'sourceskate.myshopify.com' %}

{% endif %}
```

I know the code needs to be similar to the snippet above but not sure how to add it into the code i have to add the active class to the store depending on which one you are on. Below is my code:

```html
            {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
              {%- case block.type -%}
              {%- when 'bmx-link' -%}
                <a class="link-container" href="{{ block.settings.store_link }}">
                  <div class="bmx-store">
                    <img 
                      width="15"
                      height="15"
                      src="{{ block.settings.icon_image | img_url: '15x15' }}"
                      srcset="{{ block.settings.icon_image | img_url: '15x15' }}"
                      alt="{{ block.settings.icon_image.alt }}">
                    <span>{{ block.settings.store_link_title }}</span>
                  </div>
                </a>
                {%- when 'skate-link' -%}
                  <a class="link-container" href="{{ block.settings.store_link }}">
                    <div class="skate-store">
                      <img 
                        width="15"
                        height="15"
                        src="{{ block.settings.icon_image | img_url: '15x15' }}"
                        srcset="{{ block.settings.icon_image | img_url: '15x15' }}"
                        alt="{{ block.settings.icon_image.alt }}">
                      <span>{{ block.settings.store_link_title }}</span>
                    </div>
                  </a>
              {%- endcase -%}
              {%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: Please do not use code snippets for non-functioning code. Use regular code blocks for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add class based on page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983091/jquery-add-class-based-on-page-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          {% assign bmx_class = 'bmx-store' %}
          {% assign skate_class = 'skate-store' %}
          {% if shop.name == 'bmx' %} <!-- use youre store name here -->
               {% assign bmx_class = 'bmx-store current-store' %}
          {% elsif shop.name == 'skate' %}
               {% assign skate_class = 'skate-store current-store %}
          {% endif %}
          {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
          {%- case block.type -%}
          {%- when 'bmx-link' -%}
             {% assign class_block = bmx_class %}
          {%- when 'skate-link' -%}
             {% assign class_block = skate_class %}
          {% endcase %}
         
            <a class="link-container" href="{{ block.settings.store_link }}">
              <div class="{{ class_block }}">
                <img 
                  width="15"
                  height="15"
                  src="{{ block.settings.icon_image | img_url: '15x15' }}"
                  srcset="{{ block.settings.icon_image | img_url: '15x15' }}"
                  alt="{{ block.settings.icon_image.alt }}">
                <span>{{ block.settings.store_link_title }}</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          
          {%- endfor -%}
```

If stores are more than 2 other cleaner solutions can be found.